# Why can't I center my navigation menu?

Tags: html, css

My test site here is working fine I believe (haven't tested it in all browsers quite yet however my main navigation menu at the top wont center. There is a gap there in the middle because the logo will be going there, but I didn't want it in the way for this test.

Why isn't my navigation centering?

CSS

```
    #main-navigation { width: 100%; height: 70px;font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; text-transform: uppercase; font-size: 1em; letter-spacing: 2px; line-height: 35px; margin: 0 auto;}
    #main-navigation ul { width: 289px; list-style: none; }
    #main-navigation li { float: left ;margin-left: 12px; }
    #main-navigation li a { display: block; text-decoration: none; color: #fff; }
    #main-navigation li a:hover { color: #c7bd89; }
    #main-nav-left{ list-style: none; float: left; border: 1px solid #6F0; }
    #main-nav-right{ list-style: none; float:right; border: 1px solid #6F0; }

header { width: 960px; margin: 0 auto; display: inline-block; /*border: 1px solid #000;*/}
```

HTML

```
<header>
  <nav id="main-navigation">
           <ul id="main-nav-left">
               <li class="current"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Areas of Practice</a></li>
           </ul>
          <!-- <a href="http://averylawoffice.ca/"><img class="averylogo" src="img/HEADER-AveryLawOffice-LOGO.png" alt="Avery Law Office"></a>-->
           <img class="banner" src="img/BANNER1-averylawoffice.jpg" alt="Banner 1">

           <ul id="main-nav-right">
               <li class="current"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
           </ul>

        </nav>

</header>
```

As you see I already have "margin: 0 auto;" in there. So I'm confused as to why it's not working.

[This is the site](http://ambergoodwin.com/averylawoffice/index2.html)

However if I take out display: inline-block; it works fine but when updated on my local wordpress theme it moves down a lot.

[image]

@Quoo: Do you know why this might be happening to it for the CSS is right now. Would this be a question for wordpress.stackexchange?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can define yout header display:table; as like this

```
header {
width: 960px;
margin: 0 auto;
display: table;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You want display:block not display:inline-block on your header element.

Comment: which, it should be noted is the default display value of a header element so you don't really need to specify it at all.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up however it still messes up in a different way then. I edited the original question to add in whats happening now.

Comment: When you just remove display:inline-block;, it works fine for me. Something else that you haven't posted must be causing your other issue.

Comment: Maybe it's my local server. I've made sure all the code is in there, I didn't have my rest on the local wordpress theme however it didn't change anything. I'll just have to play with it. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you don't need to add any thing in your header class if need navigation in center so it will with work your **margin:auto; & width: 960px;** like mentioned below sample:-

```
 header {
width: 960px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Your navigation will come in center according to above css.....